# Chrome Mobile color bar theme-color meta tag not working

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm trying to implement the `theme-color` meta tag but I can't see it working in my Motorola smartphone with Chrome and Android Lollipop.

I started with a `theme-color` tag then I wrote the other tags, but have had no success at all.

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#5f5eaa">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#5f5eaa">
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#5f5eaa">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#5f5eaa">
```

This webpage is running over HTTPS with an invalid certificate (it's an intranet tool), but I don't think it would affect that feature, right?

Comment: See https://crbug.com/500970 and https://crbug.com/474371

Comment: Have a cert issue here too and not seeing the color. Could be related...

Comment: Tested the theory of it being a cert issue with HTTPS and found that it indeed is why it doesn't work. Works fine over HTTPS with valid cert.

Comment: Same issue here - has no effect when using self-signed or invalid cert, but works fine with valid cert

Comment: Have you tried using the a Manifest instead? This will work on regular HTTP too. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/08/using-manifest-to-set-sitewide-theme-color

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Always check actual browsers versions.

Here is table of supporting this meta tag.
https://caniuse.com/#feat=meta-theme-color

[image]

Answer (score 54):

In my case, it actually turned out to be the theme my phone was using. The theme-color meta tag **does not work** in Android's dark theme (I'm on Android 10 at the time I'm writing this). Switch to the light theme in Chrome and you'll see it work. :)

Comment: This solved my issue! Didn't know Chrome android doesn't allow theme-color in dark mode. Is there  a way to over-ride this?

Comment: This is really a good catch. I keep forgetting it and end up here multiple times.

Answer (score 16):

A valid certification is required from my testing experience.

I had the same problem as I was testing on my localhost (i.e. the address bar background color did not change on mobile), but as soon I pushed to production (i.e. production has valid certification) I was able to view the changes reflected on the android testing devices.

Android devices used: OnePlus 3T, Huawei, an old samsung phone. All were positive results.

Comment: hi, i have a valid certificate but still for some reason i dont the address bar colored on iphone. they are working well on android

Comment: @sss999 Try this: `<!-- Chrome, Firefox OS and Opera -->
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#4285f4">
    <!-- Windows Phone -->
    <meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#4285f4">
    <!-- iOS Safari -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#4285f4">`

Answer (score 8):

Please check your browser theme? May be there enabled the dark mode!

Answer (score 6):

chrome requires you to have a valid certificate for the theme-bar color to work

Comment: basic HTTP also seems to work

Answer (score 1):

Just tested this, following @Lodmot's answer for Android 11. There is a slight (but important mention) to make:

Do **NOT** rely on the "System default" setting! In Battery Saver mode, the theme is forced to "Dark", so your `theme-color` will have no effect.

To properly test out your code, manually set Chrome's theme to "Light".